# Passing the modules name to the module constructor

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, unity-container

I'm creating a Silverlight application which will load modules defined by the user.

The is the tricky part: I don't know what modules there will be, so I don't know the names of the modules.

I've ran into a small problem: when a user-made module is loaded, it doesn't know it's name (the bootstrapper knows it at runtime), and I need some sort of name to keep track of all the modules being used by the application.

What this basically boils down to is this: I'd like to tell the module what it's expected name is (a simple string) in the module constructor.

However, AFAIK in Unity you can only pass interfaces to modules, correct? And, even if I create some very simple interface with a string property, how do I make sure that each module gets the right name (or how do I pass the correct instance of that interface)?

Answer (score 0):

Surely the module itself defines its own name, for example.

```
[Module(ModuleName="Module Name Goes Here")]
public class SomeModule : ModuleBase
{
    ....
}
```

Why would it need to be told its own name..?

Comment: I understand that this is the basic principle of PRISM... however, I'd like to be able to change this. The idea is that the application isn't really interested in what the module is actually called; what it needs is to keep track of modules loaded, and for that, it needs to keep track of internal names or IDs. At the moment the requirement is for the module to have a matching name with the config file which will be used to load said module, but if possible I'd like to lift this restriction.